# TimeZone in Tempus Dominus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, momentjs, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker, moment-timezone

I'm trying to use the TimeZone option in Bootstrap 4's Tempus Dominus (calendar) functionality. That option uses moment-timezone, of which I have already added the CDN.

My objective is to make the timezone EST (GMT-5), where right now it's guessing my local timezone which is ET (The data I'm parsing doesn't take EDT into account, so ET won't work right). How do I accomplish this? What parameter do I give the timeZone option below:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({timeZone: /*...*/, format: "MM/DD/YY kk:mm", useCurrent: false, defaultDate: dataArr[3][0][0], minDate: dataArr[3][0][0], maxDate: dataArr[3][dataArr[3].length - 1][0]});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass time zones from the IANA TZ Database.  You can find [a list of them on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

If you want your results to correctly reflect Eastern time in the US, then you must consider daylight saving time.  Ignoring it means you will be an hour off for a large part of the year.  Choose `"America/New_York"`.

If on the other hand, you are certain that you want UTC-5, fixed for the entire year, regardless that this is not the time in the US Eastern time zone for much of the year, then pick `"Etc/GMT+5"`.  (Note the sign is inverted, due to following POSIX conventions.)

Comment: That worked! For anyone else asking the same question, make sure you have the correct cdn that says "with-data".